# Update XenServer from 5.5 to 5.6 with Debian Lenny 64 bit

Tags: xenserver, debian-lenny

I have a XenServer 5.5 in production running Debian Lenny 64bit. It's not officially supported, but it's a known working configuration: [Citrix Community article explaining how to set it up](http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Configuring+Debian+(Lenny)+64-bit+(v5.04)+on+XenServer+5.5).

My question is: are there any problems with update to 5.6? Things to watch for, etc? Or should it just work out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the XenServer updated more-or-less itself (at least neither I nor any other admin didn't notice prompts about update).

So it looks like it works out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Debian Lenny 64 bit on xenserver 5.6 for some time now without any issues.
It's worth noting that i didn't migrate a 64 bit machine from 5.5 but setup a new machine.

In my experience a cheap testing environment is a really good thing to have when testing out new releases like your scenario.

The ideal is to have a identical testing environment as your production enviroment but in most cases this isen't a viable option because of the cost.

As a good practice when migrating to newer solutions you should do a isolated test run.

I would setup a isolated xenserver 5.6 with local storage only and create a snapshot from your production debian server that you export to the testing environment.

This way you could try it out without risking downtime on your production system.